# Using SELECT CASE to Manage Production Tables

Tags: vba, excel-2007, increment, select-case

I'm trying to use a Select Case to log production time-tables. 
I've tried a couple angles - one being Select Case. 
Every time I run the Macro I get the default ERROR "Wrong Model Entered...."

```
Private Sub Transfer()

Dim ModR As String
Dim Count1 As Integer
Dim Count2 As Integer
Dim Count3 As Integer
Dim Count4 As Integer
Dim Count5 As Integer

Count1 = 0
Count2 = 0
Count3 = 0
Count4 = 0
Count5 = 0

ModR = Worksheets(1).Range("B3").Value

Select Case ModR
  Case "Model 1"
    Worksheets(1).Range("B4:B6").Copy
    Worksheets(2).Range("B3:B5").Offset(Count1, 0).PasteSpecial
    Count1 = Count1 + 1
  Case "Model 2"
    Worksheets(1).Range("B4:B6").Copy
    Worksheets(2).Range("B7:B9").Offset(Count2, 0).PasteSpecial
    Count2 = Count2 + 1
  Case "Mode1 3"
    Worksheets(1).Range("B4:B6").Copy
    Worksheets(2).Range("B11:B13").Offset(Count3, 0).PasteSpecial
    Count3 = Count3 + 1
  Case "Model 4"
    Worksheets(1).Range("B4:B6").Copy
    Worksheets(2).Range("B15:B17").Offset(Count4, 0).PasteSpecial
    Count4 = Count4 + 1
  Case "Model 5"
    Worksheets(1).Range("B4:B6").Copy
    Worksheets(2).Range("B19:B21").Offset(Count5, 0).PasteSpecial
    Count5 = Count5 + 1
  Case Else
    MsgBox "Wrong Model Entered / Model Does Not Exist"
  End Select
End Sub

Public Sub call_Transfer()
  Call Transfer
End Sub
```

I'm thinking the problem lies within

```
ModR = Worksheets(1).Range("B3").Value
```

Comment: What is the value that's entered in the worksheet with the index of 1 (not necessarily the sheet named `Sheet1`) cell `B3`? Also what is the count being used for?

Comment: I would like to enter model info into sheet1, fields B3:B6. B3 contains the name of the model, of which, I would like to search for (ColumnA) on sheet2. Once it's located on sheet2, copy the fields B4:B6 from sheet1 into the fields B3:B5 (depending on the model entered B3:B5 will change so for model2 it would copy to B7:B9) of sheet2 then increment and wait for the next entry. The count is being used to serve as a place-holder for the increment.

Comment: How should I approach incrementing the fields on worksheet2? I'm trying to create an average production time per step of each model...

Comment: It's copying to B3:B5 - but it won't increment. Also, for some reason, Model3 is giving me an error. All the rest will copy to their "prospective" positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the increment to work, you have to use global variables. Also, your offset leads to the cells being shifted downwards instead of to the right. I altered your code. It will increment the offset and shift it to the right on new macro executions.

```
Dim Count1 As Integer
Dim Count2 As Integer
Dim Count3 As Integer
Dim Count4 As Integer
Dim Count5 As Integer

Private Sub Transfer()

Dim ModR As String

ModR = Worksheets(1).Range("B3").Value

Select Case ModR
  Case "Model 1"
    Worksheets(1).Range("B4:B6").Copy
    Worksheets(2).Range("B3:B5").Offset(0, Count1).PasteSpecial
    Count1 = Count1 + 1
  Case "Model 2"
    Worksheets(1).Range("B4:B6").Copy
    Worksheets(2).Range("B7:B9").Offset(0, Count2).PasteSpecial
    Count2 = Count2 + 1
  Case "Model 3"
    Worksheets(1).Range("B4:B6").Copy
    Worksheets(2).Range("B11:B13").Offset(0, Count3).PasteSpecial
    Count3 = Count3 + 1
  Case "Model 4"
    Worksheets(1).Range("B4:B6").Copy
    Worksheets(2).Range("B15:B17").Offset(0, Count4).PasteSpecial
    Count4 = Count4 + 1
  Case "Model 5"
    Worksheets(1).Range("B4:B6").Copy
    Worksheets(2).Range("B19:B21").Offset(0, Count5).PasteSpecial
    Count5 = Count5 + 1
  Case Else
    MsgBox "Wrong Model Entered / Model Does Not Exist"
  End Select
End Sub

Public Sub call_Transfer()
  Call Transfer
End Sub
```

Just paste this in your Module. I hope it's doing what you were looking for.